# Involutions in $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, power-series

Question: For a prime $p$, is every involution in $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$ with a zero constant term a reduction modulo $p$ of some involution in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$?

Here involution in $A[[x]]$ means $f\in A[[x]]$ such that $f\circ f=x$.

Obviously, a reduction mod $p$ of an involution in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ yields an involution in $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$. Moreover, at least one involution in at least one $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$ is not obtainable by reducing mod $p$, namely, $1+x\in\mathbb{F}_2[[x]]$, exactly because its constant term is nonzero. (*Update:* The second sentence in this paragraph confuses the rings of polynomials and power series, see comments and answers for corrections.)

But do we get all involutions in $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$ with the zero constant term this way?

If there is a reference where this is discussed, that would be very helpful, too.

Comment: @YCor Involution = compositional self-inverse, i.e. $f(x)$ such that $f(f(x))=x$.

Comment: @YCor I don't think we are considering involutions *of* $\mathbb F_p[[x]]$. Rather, we are considering involutions $f\in\mathbb F_p[[x]]$.

Comment: @Wojowu Exactly. As the title says, involutions _in_ $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$, not _on_ $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$. Perhaps, that was a source of confusion.

Comment: I edited so that all the discussion can be erased, of course you can re-edit if necessary.

Comment: @YCor I was just making pretty much the same edit, so all is well.

Comment: Involutions in $\mathbb F_p[[x]]$ with zero constant term are involutions of $\mathbb F_p[[x]]$, or, well, the associated topological ring automorphisms $x \to f(x)$ are.

Comment: Involutions with nonzero constant term don't really make sense, as composition of power series with nonzero constant term isn't well-defined. If you do it in the ring of polynomials, $f(x)=1+x$ does in fact lift, to $f(x)=1-x$.

Answer (score 12):

If $p \neq 2$, an involution in $\mathbb F_p[x]$ with zero constant term must have $\pm 1$ as the coefficient of $x$. If the leading coefficient is $1$, we can inductively see that each coefficient is zero (writing $f(x) = x + a x^n + \dots, f(f(x))= x+ 2a x^n + \dots $ so $a=0$.) Of course this trivial involution can be lifted.

On the other hand, if the leading coefficient is $-1$, then we can take $x f(x)$ a power series with leading coefficient $-x^2$. We can look at the unique algebra homomorphism $\mathbb F_p[[x]] \to \mathbb F_p[[x]]$ that sends $x$ to $f(x)$ and preserves the topology. Under this automorphism, $-x f(x)$ is fixed, so $\sqrt{-x f(x)}$ (unique up to $\pm 1$) is sent to itself or minus itself. Since its leading term is nonzero, it is sent to minus itself. So up to reparameterization by the invertible power series $\sqrt{-x f(x)}$, this is the standard involution $\pm 1$. We can lift $\sqrt{-x f(x)}$ to the integers, where the power series of the inverse function will also be integral, and use those to lift the involution.

In characteristic two, the situation is worse as there are more involutions. For instance we can take $ f(x)= \left( x^n/(1+x^n)\right)^{1/n}$ for any odd $n$. Some of these can be lifted (for instance if $n=1$ we can do $f(x) = -x/ (1-x)$ but I don't know if all can be.

EDIT:

In characteristic $0$, let $f(x) = - x/ (1 + c x^n)^{1/n}$ for any odd $n$ and $c$ in $\mathbb Z$, sufficiently divisible as to make that power series integral. Then $f$ is an involution: $$ 1 + c f(x)^n = 1 +  \frac{-c x^n}{ (1+ cx^n)} = \frac{1}{ 1+ cx ^n} $$ so $$f(f(x)) = - \frac{ f(x) }{ (1+ cx^n)^{1/n} } = -\frac{ -x }{ (1+cx^n)^{1/n} } (1+ cx^n)^{1/n}=x.$$ According to the theorem of Klopsch that Lubin cites, it seems tha this gives all involutions mod $2$.

Comment: Why is $\sqrt{xf(x)}$ well-defined (up to $\pm$)? I'd understand it in characteristic zero using a series for $\sqrt{1+t}$, but I'm not sure in finite odd characteristic.

Comment: @YCor The denominators in the series are all powers of two. Alternately you can build it step by step. If the coefficients of the square root are $a_n$, the equation for the degree $n$ term looks like $2 a_n = $ a polynomial in $a_1,\dots, a_{n-1}$, so has a unique solution in any field of characteristic not $2$.

Comment: @YCor: This surprised me as well, but it's true. If you have a formal power series $\mathbf{a} = a_n x^n + a_{n+1} x^{n+1} + a_{n+2} x^{n+2} + \cdots$ over a commutative ring in which $n$ and $a_n$ are invertible and $a_n$ is an $n$-th power, then you can always find a formal power series $\mathbf{b} = b_1 x^1 + b_2 x^2 + b_3 x^3 + \cdots$ satisfying $\mathbf{b}^n = \mathbf{a}$. To prove this, first set $b_1$ to be an $n$-th root of $a_1$, and then compare coefficients in the equality $\mathbf{b}^n = \mathbf{a}$ and solve the resulting system of equations in the ...

Comment: ... unknowns $b_2, b_3, \ldots$. This relies on the observation that the $x^k$-coefficient of $\mathbf{b}^n$ is $n b_1^{n-1} b_{k-n+1} + \left(\text{a universal polynomial in $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_{k-n}$}\right)$ when $k > n$, and is $b_1^n$ when $k = n$. So you can solve your system of equation recursively (finding $b_i$ from the equation obtained by comparing the $x^{i+n-1}$-coefficients, after $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_{i-1}$ have already been found), and you will only ever have to divide by $n$ in the process. This also yields a uniqueness statement after $b_1$ has been chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations (I should have figured out that the minimal denominators in the power series of $(1+t)^{1/2}$ are powers of 2, it's a standard exercise I did a while ago).

Comment: @YCor this carries over to the coefficients of $(1+t)^{1/n}$ for all $n \geq 1$: the prime factors of the denominators of the coefficients are exactly the prime factors of $n$. See my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696669/can-one-show-a-beginning-student-how-to-use-the-p-adics-to-solve-a-problem.

Comment: @darijgrinberg since your $a_n$ is invertible, your $\mathbf a$ is $(b_1x)^ng(x)$ where $g(x) \in 1 + xA[[x]]$, so showing $\mathbf a$ has a unique $n$th root once $b_1$ is chosen with $b_1^n = a_n$ is equivalent to showing each $u(x) \in 1 + xA[[x]]$ has a unique $n$th root in $1 + xA[[x]]$.  For that you can basically use Hensel's lemma for $f(t) = t^n - u(x) \in A[[x]][t]$: from $f(1) = 1 - u(x) \equiv 0 \bmod x$ and $f'(1) = n \in A^\times \subset A[[x]]^\times$, there is a unique $y(x) \in A[[x]]$ such that $f(y(x)) = 0$ and $y(x) \equiv 1 \bmod x$, meaning $y(x) \in 1 + xA[[x]]$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I said "basically use Hensel's lemma" rather than "use Hensel's lemma" since an $x$-adic absolute value on $A[[x]]$ is generally submultiplicative rather than multiplicative if $A$ is a commutative ring and not specifically an integral domain: $|A(x)B(x)|_x \leq |A(x)|_x|B(x)|_x$.  But we still have $|A(x)U(x)|_x = |A(x)|_x  = |A(x)|_x|U(x)|_x$ when $U(x) \in A[[x]]^\times = A^\times + xA[[x]]$.

Comment: Sorry I was at dinner when the meat of this discussion took place. I would have taken the opportunity to show my chops, toothless as they are. I’ll work on my own response.

Comment: @Lubin Well some small slice of your chops was on display since I learned the formula $(x^n/(1+x^n))^{1/n} from you a few years ago.

Comment: @KConrad: Believe it or not, it's the "factor out $\left(b_1x\right)^n$" part that I missed! I knew how to take $n$-th roots of a formal power series with constant term $1$ when $n$ is invertible in the base ring (though my reasoning would not involve Hensel's lemma).

Comment: Sorry, I slipped a fib into my last comment here. The correct statement is that $(1+p^2x)^{1/p}$ has $\Bbb Z$-coefficients.

Comment: @Lubin Can't that be used to do the liftings from characteristic $2$, combined with the theorem of Klopsch you mentioned? One could lift $x/ (1+x^n)^{1/n}$ as $- x/(1+ n^2 x^n)^{1/n} $, which is invertible because $y= -x/(1+n^2 x^n)^{1/n}$ gives $y^n (1+n^2 x^n) = -x^n$ or $x^n+y^n + n^2 x^n y^n$ which is symmetric in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Ah, but @WillSawin, you’ve lifted to char zero an involution mod $2$, but nobody says the result is going to be an involution. Maybe there’s some cohomology here?

Comment: @Lubin I as trying to argue that it is with the stuff about $y$, but let's try to do it more traditionally. If $f(x) =- x/ (1+n^2 x^n)^{1/n}$,  then $1+n^2 f(x)^n=1 -  n^2 x^n / (1+n^2 x^n) = 1/ (1+n^2 x^n), so $f(f(x)) = - f(x) / ( 1+ n^2 f(x)^n))^{1/n} = x (1+n^2 f(x)^n )^{1/n}  / (1+n^2 f(x)^n )^{1/n} =x$, so in fact the lift is an involution. Then to lift an involution conjugate to that, we can lift the conjugating invertible power series to an arbitrary invertible lift.

Comment: I seem to be not understanding, @WillSawin — a common occurrence these days. Are you saying that a lift is $-x/(1+n^2x^n)^{1/n}$, and that it’s an involution in $\Bbb Z[[x]]$? I tried that with $n=3$ and it doesn’t work: coeff of $x^4$  in $f\circ f$ is $-6$. The formula certainly gives $f\circ f\equiv x\pmod2$, of course.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, that's what I'm trying to say. I messed up my formulas by somehow writing them in the wrong order. I will try to redo them better, but first we have $f(x) =-x + 3 x^4 + \dots$, so $f ( f(x)) =- (x+ 3x^4) + 3 (-x + 3x^4)^4 + \dots = =x - 3x^4 + 3x^4 +\dots$, no?

Comment: @WillSawin, please see my addendum below. And thanks.

Answer (score 11):

This is algebraic dynamics, a big field that I’m outsider to, though I have made some peripheral contributions to it.

First, I’m assuming that you’re asking about ring automorphisms of $\Bbb Z[[x]]$ and of $\Bbb F_p[[x]]$, and the involutions from among these. Under this assumption, $x\mapsto1+x$ *is not* an involution of $\Bbb F_2[[x]]$, since it wants to take the nonunit $x$ to the unit $1+x$.

Second, and more generally, in view of the fact that all automorphisms of $\Bbb F_q[[x]]$ are necessarily continuous, we don’t need to specify that our involution $x\mapsto u(x)$ have no constant term in $u$.

Third, though Will has described an infinite set of nonconjugate involutions (in the group of all invertible series over $\Bbb F_2$), as I recall, according to a theorem of Klopsch, these are all that there are out there, in this $\Bbb F_2$-case.

Finally, all the involutions of $\Bbb Z[[x]]$ that I know about are (naturally) the $[-1]$-automorphisms of $\Bbb Z$-formal group laws, and these look like $-x+cx^q\pmod{x^{q+1}}$ for a prime power $q$. Surely there are other involutions in this situation, but I don’t know them. In particular, if you try $n=5$ here, you get a series $x+x^6+\cdots\in\Bbb F_2[[x]]$ that doesn’t seem to come from $[-1]_F(x)\in\Bbb Z[[x]]$ for any $\Bbb Z$-formal group law $F$. But globally-defined formal group laws I’m rather ignorant about. Nobody’s saying, either, that a $\Bbb Z$-involution has to belong to a formal group over $\Bbb Z$.

I think your question has to remain unanswered, at least with the expertise exhibited here so far.

---

**EDIT — Addendum**:

All thanks to Will Sawin for his persistence in the face of my repeated careless computational errors. The principle involved is that for an integral domain $R$, the map on the semigroup of formal series under substitution $u(x)\in R[[x]]$ with no constant term and $u'(0)\ne0$, namely
$$
u(x)=xw(x)\mapsto \bigl(u(x^m))^{1/m}=x\bigl(w(x^m)\bigl)^{1/m}\,,
$$
is a homomorphism, as long as it’s defined. For definedness, you need $u'(0)=w(0)$ to have an $m$-th root in the base, and more broadly, you need some sort of convergence theorem to tell you that you can take the $m$-th root of the series $w(x)$.

In the comments, I pointed out that $(1+p^2x)^{1/p}\in\Bbb Z[[x]]$, and this means that $(1+m^2x)^{1/m}\in\Bbb Z[[x]]$ as well, for any positive integer $m$.

Will says, start with the fundamental involution $u(x)=-x/(1+x)=\sum_1^\infty(-x)^n$, first apply $u(x)\mapsto u(m^2x)/m^2=U(x)$, and apply the “stretching-out” operation above, which will be defined as long as $U'(0)=-1$ has an $m$-th root in $\Bbb Z$, namely as long as $m$ is odd. Since $U(X^m)=-x^m+m^2x^{2m}-m^4x^{3m}+\cdots=-x^m[1-m^2x^m+m^4x^{2m}-\cdots]$, the conditions for the existence of the $m$-th root are satisfied. Thus $\bigl(U(x^m)\bigr)^{1/m}$ is a good lifting to $\Bbb Z[[x]]$ of the characteristic-two involution of the form $-x(1+g(x^m))$ for $m$ odd.